# Is it possible to retrieve the configured rooms/locations in the fulfillment service?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have been experimenting with Google Smart Home and the protocol flow looks very clear for me. In summary:

- `action.devices.SYNC` - sent by Google Smart Home to fulfillment service to find out the available devices
- `action.devices.EXECUTE` - sent by Google Smart Home to fulfillment service to execute a certain action on a device

On the smartphone/tablet, the customer can place a device in a certain location. This allows him to ask questions such as *Turn everything in my office off*. Internally, Google Smart Home knows which devices are located in the office, and sends a `action.devices.EXECUTE` action for each device in the office subsequently, as explained above.

I am now wondering about the following: is it possible to retrieve the configured locations/rooms in the fulfillment service also? Is this information exposed and available to retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to receive information about a user's home layout through the Home Graph API. When the user gives a command like "Turn everything in my office off", you may get several `OnOff` commands in your fulfillment, although you will have no way of knowing the original query.

Comment: Thanks for feedback!